# Sums or products

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Place the numbers 1 to 12 on twelve of the cells of this board, precisely two on each row and each column. The sum or product of the two numbers in each row must be the number on its right, while the sum or product of the two numbers in each column must be the number below it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer is as follows:

> [image: Puzzle]

Answer (score 0):

> [image]

Probably this could be a solution

Comment: I think you are supposed to place all the numbers from 1 to 12, with no duplicates.

Comment: Indeed, no duplicates.

Comment: Then I missed it. :)